# PHP / Ajax cannot send value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have problem with ajax and php.I have next code

```
$("form").submit(function() {
 var poruka = $("#poruka").val();
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ajax/gather/send/"+ poruka + "/'.$id.'",
        success: function(){
         loaduj('.$id.');
         alert("Your message is "+poruka);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("fail");
        }
    });
});
```

"poruka" is the message and it's taken from form

```
<form action='javascript:;'>
<input type='text' name='poruka' id='poruka' placeholder='Poruka..' style='width:100%;'>
<input type='button' name='button' hidden>
</form>
```

And when i try to send to php it won't insert that into database :

Php code :

```
$text = $_POST['text'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
if($text != ""){
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages (text,id2) VALUES ('$text','$id')") or     die(mysql_error());
}
```

And it can't work..How can i fix it ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use POST instead of GET. In your AJAX form you specify that you use **GET**, but in PHP you use `$_POST` superglobal.

Change `$_POST` into `$_GET` in your PHP code and it should work :)

Also if you do not specify method in your  tag, the default is **GET**.

From experience, in case if the data from the form is not written/updated in/to the database use

```
echo mysql_error();
```

after the MySQL query and also open the developer tools on your browser and inspect in the network panel. Developer tools can be opened using F12 and with *CTRL+SHIFT+I* if your *F12* is not working due to the coffee spilled on it. Network panel shows the data being sent, the method used and every other detail of a network call. Also there you can see the response of your server side script which in this case would return a mysql error message because you echo'ed it out.

Comment: No problem, hope that helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

The usual deal is to first locate the problem, then post:

- Form not calling JS
- JS not making the request
- PHP not getting the variable

[SQL injection](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) detected

Comment: SQL injection is not the case at this point. He just wants to have a simple code working, not to implement full functionality when even a simple thing does not work as expected

Comment: i can not be speaking on the part of the author - what he does or does not want, but usually you don't write code to keep it in a sealed box with you being the only person to ever open it. There can be trouble with the given SQL; it's a mere warning.

Comment: That's good, however I believe your answer does not suit the question here :)

Comment: SQL injection detected is not answer. The answer is debug first O-)

Comment: Yes, debugging is one of the methods every programmer uses when something does not work. I believe the question author is fully aware of it :)